# vuejs: Component for <tr>, how to implement?

Tags: vue.js

After reading docs & forums for hours... still have no answer.

Have the following JS/HTML:

```js
Vue.component("my-component", {
    props: ["id"],
    
    render: function(h) {
        return h("tr", this.$slots.default);
    }
});
    
    
var vapp = new Vue();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr is="my-component" :name="yo">
        <td>
            <span v-text="name"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Use tr + "is" attribute to specify component within the table otherwise browser will hoist it out as invalid content. **Done**

Use render + h("tr"...) because vuejs doesn't render tr element, but instead table > td and again browser hoist it out.**Done**

Now I have table > tr > td rendered well but how can I add children bound to the props/data, so I will see "yo" on the screen.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

If the elements in the slot need access to data inside the *component*, then you need to use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

Since you are using a render function, the scoped slot is available as a function through `this.$scopedSlots.default()` and you pass it an object with the data you want to be made available to the scoped slot.

You also need to define the scoped slot in the template. Here is an example.

```js
Vue.component("my-component", {
    props: ["id", "name"],
    
    render: function(h) {
        return h("tr", this.$scopedSlots.default({name: this.name}));
    }
});
    
    
var vapp = new Vue({ el:"#app"});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<table>
    <tr is="my-component" :name="'yo'">
      <template scope="{name}">
        <td>
            <span v-text="name"></span>
        </td>
      </template>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: The example above works. Thanks a lot! Are these props, within the scoped slot, reactive? Did some example, seems like are not.

Comment: What about methods? May I supply event handlers to the scoped slot?
P.S. Seems like vuejs forces me to work in data driven mode. But all I want is to enrich rendered, on server side, HTML.

Comment: @user2528473 What is passed will be reactive if you pass an observed property. In the example above, the prop is just a string, so it isn't. If a data property was passed it would be. You can pass functions through the scoped slot if you want, just add them to the object passed as the argument. It's true, Vue is a data driven library. The rendered DOM is intended to be a reflection of state.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `.vue` files you can have the table row component defined like this:

```
<template>
  <tr>{{ name }}</tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'table-row',
    props: ['name'],
  };
</script>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<table>
  <tr is="TableRow" name="Some name here"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to render HTML on server side and have vuejs component to enrich that table row with some functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <!-- ...some th -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>..</rd>
        </tr>
        <template> <row-component my-param="blabla"></row-component> <!-- component return full row <tr>...</tr>     --> 
        <some-other-recomponent my-par="blabla"></some-other-recomponent> <!-- component return full row <tr>...</tr>    -->
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your're interested in returning multiple rows from your component, you can do like this.

In your main component.

```
<table width="90%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="1%">#</th>
        <th>header description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <template>
        <your-child-component
                :prop="prop-data"
                v-for="(lancamento, index) in lancamentos"
                :key="lancamento.id">
        </your-child-component
    </template>
</table>
```

And inside your child component

```
<template>
    <tbody> <!-- dont forget this tag -->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" v-html="prop.id"></td>
            <td><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>
```